# Karate - is it possible to find element according to part of its parameter

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate I would like to know If it is possible to search input field (or some different element) using part of attribute string value?

For example, suppose that I want to find input field according to part of its "placeholder" attribute value - e.g. the placeholder attribute contains word "long" (I know the input field should have own ID but suppose that there is only placeholder value - no ID, no name value):

```
<input placeholder="Very long string contains many words" type="text">
```

Is there possibility to do anything like this?:

```
* retry().input("input[^placeholder='long', '123123123']")
```

Thank you.