# Karate - locateAll filter and input field

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate, according to [Karate - is it possible to find element according to part of its parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66857999/karate-is-it-possible-to-find-element-according-to-part-of-its-parameter) I have tried to do that using:

```
* def filter = function(x){ return x.attribute('placeholder').startsWith('Very') }
* def list = locateAll('input[placeholder]', filter)
```

But I have no idea how to use it for inserting the value. I have tried this:

```
* retry().input(list[0], '12312312311111')
```

and this:

```
* retry().input('list[0]', '12312312311111')
```

but neither worked.

Have you any idea what is wrong in syntax?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever `locate` returns is an `Element` object. So you can call methods on it. Please read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#locate

So this should work:

```
* list[0].input('12312312311111')
* list[0].retry().input('12312312311111')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. Karate is such powerfull testing framework. I like it more and more :)